# memory increases channel capacity?

Tags: information-theory, entropy, mutual-information

I learnt in $\textit{Elements of Information Theory -Cover & Thomas}$ that $\underline{\text{memory increases the capacity of a channel}}$.

A transmitter sends $X_i$ and the receiver receives $h_iX_i+w_i$, for all $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$. $h_i$'s  and $w_i$'s are unknown to the receiver as well as transmitter except for its statistics.

Consider a binary channel with output $\boxed{ Y_i= 1, \text{if }  |h_iX_i+w_i|^{2} > 1, \text{ else } Y_i=0}$

Here $X_i, Y_i \in\{0,1\}$. $w_i$'s are iid with $ w_i \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,1)$ and is independent of $X_i'$s. Also, $h_{i} \equiv h \sim \mathcal{C} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and is independent of $w_i$'s and $X_i$'s. Here **$h_i$'s are equal (random but fixed across the channel uses). This means there is memory.**

I am interested in finding the capacity of this channel with memory given by

\begin{aligned}
&\max I\left(X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots, X_{n} ; Y_{1}, Y_{2}, \ldots, Y_{n}\right) \\
&\quad=H\left(X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots, X_{n}\right)-H\left(X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots, X_{n} \mid Y_{1}, Y_{2}, \ldots, Y_{n}\right).
\end{aligned}

My goal is to show that **this capacity will be more than the capacity of the same channel model with i.i.d $h_i$'s**.

I'm interested in the **non-coherent case where $h_i$'s are not known**.

Can someone help me solve this?

Comment: If $h_i$ is a random "fixed-constant" chosen from  $h_i \equiv h \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,1)$, I believe you can factorize $|X_i+\frac{\bar{h}}{|h^2|}w_i| > \frac{1}{|h|}$, so by calling the new random variables $\xi_i = \frac{\bar{h}}{|h^2|}w_i$ and the new random threshold $\epsilon = \frac{1}{h}$, the problem is like having a "probability" $h$ of calling someone by a specific channel (like cellphone, or telephone, smoke signals, etc), with each channel having and individual different communication process given by $|X_i + \xi_i|>\epsilon$, and I don´t see from where the memory-property arises?

Comment: @Joako Can I do this if the $h_i$'s are unknown.? I am interested in the non-coherent case implying $h_i$'s are not known.